# Using R 'Data Table' to carry out the following calculations

Tags: r, data.table

I have a very large data set which I want to carry out the following procedures to do some analysis.
The raw data is on a transactional basis so it gives me incremental amounts for each ID. I have then calculated the running totals for each ID and banded them into Small (0-100k), Medium(100k - 1m) and Large(>£1m) buckets.

What I want to achieve is the table to the right. I want to have a view of this data by transactional period (Year-Month), the size band and on a cumulative basis.  So for example in the small band by 2017-01 I have 2 ID's which add up to 100, and by 2017-03 the amount in first ID moves to the medium bucket and so we take away the initial amount of 80 relating to this ID and move it to the medium bucket.

I am using data table to carry out the following manipulation, but don't know if there is a better way to do this. The appearance columns are there for illustrations as I want to also get a count column which gives me the number of ID's in each band at different periods.

My code so far is as follows:

```
Data <- Data[, Cumulative_Sum := cumsum(Amounts_Incremental), by =.(ID)
```

`Data <- Data[, Band := ifelse(Cumulative_Sum <= 100000, "Small", ifelse(Cumulative_Sum <= 1000000, "Medium", "Large"))]`

```
ID  Period  Amounts (Incremental)   Cumulative Sum  Band    Appearance Small    Appearnace Medium   Appearnace Large
1   2017-01 80  80  Small   1   0   0
1   2017-03 400 480 Medium  -1  1   0
1   2017-09 500 980 Medium  0   0   0
1   2018-01 100 1080    Large   0   -1  1
2   2017-05 200 200 Medium  0   1   0
2   2017-06 4000    4200    Large   0   -1  1
2   2018-02 300 4500    Large   0   0   0
2   2018-03 200 4700    Large   0   0   0
2   2018-04 400 5100    Large   0   0   0
3   2017-01 20  20  Small   1   0   0
3   2017-05 10  30  Small   0   0   0
3   2018-01 30  60  Small   0   0   0
3   2018-03 40  100 Medium  -1  1   0
3   2018-04 8   108 Medium  0   0   0

Output  Small Amounts   Medium Amounts  Large Amounts   Count   Count   Count
2017-01 100 0   0   2   0   0
2017-02 100 0   0   2   0   0
2017-03 20  480 0   1   1   0
2017-04 20  480 0   1   1   0
2017-05 30  680 0   1   2   0
2017-06 30  480 4200    1   1   1
2017-07 30  480 4200    1   1   1
2017-08 30  480 4200    1   1   1
2017-09 30  980 4200    1   1   1
2017-10 30  980 4200    1   1   1
2017-11 30  980 4200    1   1   1
2017-12 30  980 4200    1   1   1
2018-01 60  0   5280    1   0   2
2018-02 60  0   5580    1   0   2
2018-03 0   100 5780    0   1   2
2018-04 0   108 6180    0   1   2
2018-05 0   108 6180    0   1   2
2018-06 0   108 6180    0   1   2
2018-07 0   108 6180    0   1   2
```

PS: I didn't know how to format this better.

[image]

Comment: Please include a copy&paste example of your data, not an image, this way we can reproduce it easily. Use `dput()` or build an example yourself, thanks.

Comment: Read `help("cut")`.

Comment: I have added the table, but unsure how to get the formatting to be reader friendly. Hope this helps